# Excel stops opening XLSM file after running code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

After running this code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath, UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Excel opening my file with blank page, all pages exist in VBA editor.
All menu items is not accessible

[image]
[image]

Whats hapens?

SOLVED:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Visible:=False
```

You ordered it to be invisible. Try setting the property to *True*.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, you can do so via the View (sorry, no Cyrillic knowledge) > Window > Unhide icon.

Comment: not helpful  (( i get error  Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: `ActiveWindow.Visible = True`?

Comment: oh yes i found this dialog windows